# Add a non continuous range as a data source for sparkline in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sparklines

I would like to ask if it is possible to add a non continuous range as a data source to create a sparkline. Without VBA it can be done by creating a named range, provided that data are on the same worksheet and using that named range as a data source.

My named range is called "SPA". I can even record a macro, but when I run the recorded macro on the correct activesheet I get **Application-defined or object-defined error**.

This is the code that was generated when recording the macro
`Range("$B$2").SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkColumn, SourceData:="SPA"`

Here is another code, which I actually use in my macro, where all the ranges are fully qualified
`SM.Range("A2").SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkColumn, SourceData:=SM.Range("SPA")`

In both cases I get **Application-defined or object-defined error.**
I have a custom to rename Sheet1, Sheet2, etc. codenames to own abbreviations, so that I do not need to qualify sheets in every macro.
So I use `SM.Range("A2")` instead of `Dim SM as Worksheet: Set SM = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SM")` so the error does not relate to the ranges not being fully qualified.

When I use add sparkline manually without VBA and I use the named range, the non continuous data source range works.

Thank you very much for any hints.

Comment: Sounds like you've set the `scope` of SPA to `Worksheet`, not `Workbook`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is set to Workbook in name manager. I also tried `SourceData:=Range("SPA")` or just `SourceData:="SPA"` with no avail.

When creating the range programatically, I tried both
`ThisWorkbook.names.Add name:="SPA", RefersTo:=rng.Address`
and
`ThisWorkbook.names.Add name:="SPA", RefersTo:=rng`
but no luck either.

Comment: Is the worksheet protected perhaps?

Comment: No, it is not. Are you able to add a non continuous range to a sparkline ( in my case it is $B$5,$B$9,$B$13,$B$17,$B$21,$B$25,$B$29,$B$33,$B$37,$B$41,$B$45,$B$49)  by any other VBA code that is actually working? The sparkline is in cell B2. I just want to figure out if it is a bug, or that I have something wrong.

Comment: Yes. `Range("$B$2").SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkColumn, SourceData:="SPA"` works fine for me, with SPA set to a non-contiguous range. Have you tested yourself on a completely new workbook?

Comment: Yes, it works in a blank workbook. So the issue must be workbook specific, e.g. merged cells, etc... Thank you very much. I know know where to look at.